# Show form if radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

How can I show my form content based on which radio button I have checked? Currently I have something like this:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
   var selected = $('input:checked[type="radio"]').val();
    if(selected == 'true') {
      $('.fee').show();
     } else if(selected == 'false') {
        $('.fee').hide();
    }
 });

var prev = $(".subscription_button:checked");

$(".subscription_button").change(function() {
    if(confirm('really?'))
         { 
           prev = $(this); 
         }
     else{
            prev.prop('checked','checked');   
        }    
});
```

views:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td>
     Seller Fee?
    </td>
    <td>
    <%= radio_button("seller", "need_fee", "true", class: "subscription_button") %>
    <%= radio_button("seller", "need_fee", "false") %>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="fee" style="display:none;">
    <td>Set fee</td>
    <td><%= f.number_field :fee  %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

It is actually working when I change radio button from false to true, but what I want is that when **by default button true is checked, the class "fee" is being displayed**, and if by default the button false is checked, the class "fee" will display none. Thanks.

Comment: call the `$('input[type="radio"]').change()` manually after you create the event handler or have `$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
   var selected = $('input:checked[type="radio"]').val();
    if(selected == 'true') {
      $('.fee').show();
     } else if(selected == 'false') {
        $('.fee').hide();
    }
 }).change()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change this line:

```
<tr class="fee" style="display:none;">
```

To this:

```
<tr class="fee" style="<%= 'display:none' unless f.object.need_fee %>">
```

Hope this help. :)

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to trigger the `change` event on the `checked` button at DOM ready like so:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
   //your working code
})
.filter(':checked').change(); //<<<<--- ADD THIS
```

Comment: Hello, I prefer your answer more, but I have a confirm message on radio button change(look at my edited question), and this will cause the confirm message to pop up everytime i refresh the page. Any idea how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Define another variable after `prev`, `var n = 0;`. Then change your condition to: `n++ && confirm('.........')` .

Comment: In this case, if the button is false by default, I couldn't get the confirm message on the first click to true button.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand what the additional question is. Would you kindly describe the behavior you're trying to achieve? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add a load (or ready) event:

```
  $('input[type="radio"]').load(function() {
    var selected = $('input:checked[type="radio"]').val();
     if(selected == 'true') {
       $('.fee').show();
      } else if(selected == 'false') {
         $('.fee').hide();
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function for this:

```
var selected = $('input:checked[type="radio"]').val();
if(selected == 'true') {
  $('.fee').show();
 } else if(selected == 'false') {
    $('.fee').hide();
}
```

then call it both on DOM load and on radio-button change.